# Using Perl to split a float

Tags: perl, split, floating-point, precision

Why did I lose precision using split? 
My goal is to get just the fractional part, all of it.

```
$a = 123456789.123456789;
@b = split(/\./, $a);
$baseDec = "." . $b[1];
```

Above gives $baseDec == .123457

But this gives the correct precision:
Is it the right way to do it?  **CORRECTION: THIS GIVES THIS SAME BAD PRECISION!
  I did not properly test the code. Sorry!**

```
$a = 123456789.123456789;
@b = split(/\./, $a);
$baseInt = $b[0];
$baseDec = $a - $baseInt;
```

Should I be using Math::BigFloat?

**Edit:** $a should be a string `$a = "123456789.123456789";` and then the original code works. Until I figure out how to get my Perl to work with longdouble, I can't test the original question. The answer seems to be that I lost precision because $a is being stored in a double (52 bits ~ 15 decimal digits, as @Ben stated below). `print $a` gives `123456789.123457`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you're going to treat it as a string, do so all the way through.  You wouldn't assign a string without quoting, right?

```
my $a = "123456789.123456789";
```

Comment: Yes, you saw through my accidentally deceptive question! $a was actually a string in my code, and it works fine if I keep it that way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`int`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html):

```
 $a = 123456789.123456789;
 $baseDec = $a - int($a);
```

Comment: Have you actually tested this? When I tried it `printf("%.9f", $baseDec);` resulted in `0.123456791`, not `0.123456789`.

Answer (score 4):

You lost precision because `123456789.123456789` is a numeric literal which, by default, the Perl compiler stores in a `double` (52 bits, ~15 decimal digits) `$a`. Next, when `@b = split(/\./, $a);` runs, `$a` is implicitly coerced into a string before it can be `split`.

If your Perl were compiled to use `longdouble`s (See: `perl -V:uselongdouble` and `perl -V:doublesize`), the numeric literal would have been represented with 80 bits (~21 decimal digits) and string coercion.

Comment: `perl -V` on Linux gave me the same as you. On Sun4-Solaris, it was (reversed byte order -- **not a problem**):  `intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=87654321`    `d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16`

Comment: Does your your original code work correctly on Solaris?

Comment: No, my code does not work as stated. I made the mistake of writing the question without proper testing! $a should be a string, and then the code works. I think longdouble is not being used. `print $a` gives `123456789.123457`. Thanks @Ben for the time you took to unravel a deceptive question!

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using sprintf:

```
my $a = 123456789.123456789;
my @b = split(/\./, sprintf("%.8f",$a));
my $baseDec = "." . $b[1];
print $baseDec;
```

Comment: Don't you mean `"%.9f"`?

Comment: Even then the result is not correct (`.123456791`, not `.123456789`). `printf("%.15f", $a)` results in `123456789.123456791043282`.